# Does changing career delete progress on the D career?

Tags: need-for-speed-rivals

In Need for Speed Rivals, I have not tried changing careers, as I am worried I will lose my progress, considering I have a Lamborghini vendor. The reason I want to know is that I would like to have both a cop and a racer career.

Answer (score 1):

Need for Speed Rivals does not have multiple save functionality. You have a few options depending on if you are playing on PC or on console.

If you are playing on PC you can simply backup your save which would be saved in this location `%USERPROFILE% \Documents\Ghost Games\Need for Speed(TM) Rivals\settings\ <user-id>.sav`

If you are playing on a console you can create a second profile, or back up your data on a flash drive to keep your previous save game.